# Why is this information not being passed from one class to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I'm trying to get this information to send across from a class called `ViewController` to another class. In `viewController` I have a `NSDictionary` called `selectedVenues`. Then in the other class I also have a `NSDictionary` called `selectedVenues`. I would like to send the information from `ViewController selectedVenues` to the other class' selectedVenue but it is only returning null;

```
ViewController *main = nil;
self.selectedVenue = main.selectedVenues;
NSDictionary *selectedLocation = self.selectedVenue[@"location"];
NSString *selectedLat = selectedLocation[@"lat"];
NSString *selectedLng = selectedLocation[@"lng"];
```

I have tried this now. And it is still not working

```
ViewController *main = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

       //self.selectedVenue = main.selectedVenues;
       NSDictionary *selectedLocation =  [main getSelectedVenue:@"location"];
       NSString *selectedLat = selectedLocation[@"lat"];
       NSString *selectedLng = selectedLocation[@"lng"];
```

This is the method in my viewController.

```
-(NSDictionary *)getSelectedVenue:(NSString *)key;
{

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    self.selectedVenue= [self.venues objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
     NSDictionary *selectedLocation = self.selectedVenue[key];

    return selectedLocation;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `selectedVenues` of `nil`?

Comment: You have to `init` your ViewController.

Comment: More code is required, however why are you copying the data at all (why not add a method to `ViewController` that gets just the location you are interested in)?

Comment: -trojanfoe I have taken your advice but it is still not working.

Answer (score 4):

```
ViewController *main = nil;
self.selectedVenue = main.selectedVenues;
```

What did you expect to happen when you reference a `nil` value?

*but it is only returning null;*

Yup, that's valid.

Comment: No need to appologize for being new, we all were at one point. You're lucky you're using Objective C with this though, in many languages, using a null value would result in a program crash.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize the `viewController` in order to get its dictionary values, in your code

```
ViewController *main = nil;
```

you should initialize it with the nib or the viewController you are using

```
ViewController *main = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value before pushing the viewController..

In your ViewController.m

```
NextViewController *main = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
main.selectedVenue = self.selectedVenue;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
```